# Pass certain values or parameters on response - django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

So I have this code which is which is adding field to the response object, and I would like to access the variable on the front end.

```
import time
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ResponseTimeInstrumentation(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.instrumentation_start_time = time.time()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        duration = time.time()-request.instrumentation_start_time
        response["page_loading_duration"] = duration
        return response
```

I know the response.content is already rendered but I want this field somehow to be accessible on the front end

Comment: You wish to use `"page_loading_duration"` in a django templates?

Comment: Yes, That was I can do display it or do something on the front end